# Вычисления корня из произведения

Tags: алгоритм, c, c++

Доброго времени суток!
Дано нескольких чисел порядка 10^12, **не являющихся квадратами**, *произведение* которых **гарантированно** является квадратом некоторого числа. Проблема в том, что, произведение это, очевидно, > 10^20 то есть значительно превышает размер *unsigned long long*.
Собственно, вопрос: как из этого произведения вычислить **точный** корень за как можно меньшее время?
Появляется естественное желание раскладывать числа на простые множители, после чего перемножать заново, но их брать степени в два раза меньше. Но разложение таких чисел каждого займет много времени и памяти.
Заранее спасибо всем откликнувшимся!

Comment: Вроде как факторизация - штука относительно быстрая.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Давайте попробуем вот как:

Пусть наши числа *a*, *b*, и их разложение на простые множители выглядит так:

[image]

Можно посчитать *t* = НОД(*a*, *b*), *не раскладывая числа на множители* при помощи алгоритма Евклида, тогда

[image]

где

[image]

Рассмотрим числа

[image]

Эти числа обязаны являться квадратами, т. к. каждый простой показатель степени входит либо в *a₀*, либо в *b₀* (ясно, почему?). Из них можно извлечь корень.

Далее,

[image]

Всё.

---

В качестве альтернативного решения: вычислим приблизительный корень типа `double` из каждого сомножителя. Точность вычисления корня (`sqrt(double)`) 52 значащих бита, то есть 15 десятичных разрядов. Для чисел точностью в 12 разрядов корень будет около 6 разрядов, то есть точность корня будет `15 - 9 = 6` знаков после запятой. То же для второго сомножителя. Перемножим полученные корни. Точность произведения будет 5 знаков после запятой. Округлив произведение до целого, получим точный результат (для этого достаточен был бы 1 знак после запятой, а у нас их аж 5).

---

PS: почему бы не включить математическую нотацию здесь, как и на маткоде?

Comment: разве на хешкоде есть автоматическая отрисовка формул введенных с помощью LaTex?

Comment: @miramentis: Нету. :-) Это картинки.

Comment: ваши рассуждения вполни логичны для 2-ух чисел, но я не совсем понимаю, как это осуществить для большего количества чисел, не вычисляя НОД попарно для всех чисел, что, вроде как, будет весьма накладно.

Comment: @miramentis: Да, для `n` чисел сложнее. Но это уже вопрос на математику, а не к нам.

Comment: @miramentis: А как насчёт альтернативного решения в лоб?

Comment: а как тут в лоб-то вычислишь? в unsigned long long не влезает.  

собственно, я надеялся, что есть какие-то алгоритмы для решения подобных задач и тут мне помогут, но, похоже, Вы правы, пойду к математикам...

Comment: @miramentis: Ну, я ж написал в ответе, как именно. Вкратце, взять корень из каждого сомножителя, перемножить и округлить.

Comment: @VladD найти разложение на множители. Сложить степени множителей, поделить пополам,  высчитать корень. А на мою рекомендацию gmp внимания обращать не хочут.

Comment: @alexlz: искать разложение на множители долго вроде бы. GMP, кстати, тоже хорошее решение, и я бы на месте автора использовал его, но вроде ж эта конкретная задача решится и без GMP?

Comment: @VladD Числа большие (10^20 для нескольких 10^12 -- чересчур скромная оценка), округление может и подвести

Comment: @alexlz: оценка точности у меня в ответе есть, вроде должно покатить. Или я просчитался где-то?

Comment: @VladD смущает неопределённость термина "несколько"... (в смысле несколько чисел по миллиону)

Comment: @alexlz: Это условие задачи поменялось, раньше было строго 2. В любом случае, это не должно менять оценки при количестве слагаемых меньшем 10^4.

Comment: @VladD: я проверил вариант с округлением, действительно, хорошо справляется при числах порядка 10^12, вроде ошибок не выдает.  
при необходимости работы с большими числами, я соглашусь с @alexlz, использовать GMP - наилучший вариант

Comment: @alexlz: Может, преобразуете ваш комментарий в ответ?

Answer (score 2):

GNU MP не спасёт отца русской демократии?

Answer (score 2):

Алгоритм [VladD](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/10105/vladd) можно распространить на случай нескольких чисел. Для этого надо в цикле брать пару очередных элементов массива и вычислять их НОД и НОК. НОК помещать в конец массива (как на рисунке), а НОД перемножать.
Если корень извлекается нацело, то через (n-1) шагов он будет равен произведению НОД.
[image: Корень НОД]

Answer (score 0):

Например, вот:[Алгоритмы нахождения квадратного корня](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8C#.D0.90.D0.BB.D0.B3.D0.BE.D1.80.D0.B8.D1.82.D0.BC.D1.8B_.D0.BD.D0.B0.D1.85.D0.BE.D0.B6.D0.B4.D0.B5.D0.BD.D0.B8.D1.8F_.D0.BA.D0.B2.D0.B0.D0.B4.D1.80.D0.B0.D1.82.D0.BD.D0.BE.D0.B3.D0.BE_.D0.BA.D0.BE.D1.80.D0.BD.D1.8F).

Comment: поправил свой вопрос.  
необходимо точное значение корня

Comment: Ну, если точность вычисления корня хорошая (eps < 0.5), можно просто округлить до целого.

Comment: Вы ведь заметили, что там вовсе не один метод приводится, не так ли?

Comment: @falstaf, там, вроде как корень из конкретного числа, а не из произведения. ну это если я внимательно смотрел

Answer (score 0):

Берите любую библиотеку реализующую `Big Integer`/`BigInt` и будет вам счастье...

Comment: уже подсказали GMP. просто хотелось обойтись без дополнительных либ